# Launch FtpRequest in winRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, httpclient, ftp-client

i'm looking for an example describing the process of an ftprequest under winrt to download/upload files from server, i found examples using webclient but Winrt doesn't support that and besides HttpClient doesn't support FTP. Help please. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in support for FTP on WinRT.

There are a bunch of examples on how to do it though. Here's one from the MSDN samples. I have not tested it to see how good it is.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWindowsStoreAppFTPDownloa-88a90bd9/view/SourceCode#content

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that was what almost what i was looking for, is there an upload example please? thx :)

Comment: You'll have to look. None built in.